# Android Management API and VpnService

Tags: android, google-console-developer, android-management-api

I'm using android tablets in kiosk mode where only one application is allowed. And I also use 3G network. To save traffic, I use the special launcher on every application which uses `VpnService` android API. And also this launcher prevents a user from accessing to other apps.

Android Management API provides kiosk mode functionality, but I don't see any reference to VPN configuration. How can I configure network traffic with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure always-on-VPN with the Android Management API by setting `alwaysOnVpnPackage` and `vpnConfigDisabled` in the [Policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies):

```
{
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "my.vpn.app",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
  ],
  "alwaysOnVpnPackage": {
    "packageName": "my.vpn.app",
    "lockdownEnabled": true
  },
  "vpnConfigDisabled": true
}
```

If your VPN app supports managed configurations you can configure it via the Policy without manual interaction. Otherwise you will have to configure the VPN app manually the first time before turning on kiosk mode.

Comment: Ok, thank you! But Should I run special VPN application? Or I can use policy file just to restrict all other applications from being run in the background, don't you know?

Comment: You need a VPN app to set up the VPN connection, this VPN app can run in the background and all the data will go through the connection without any set up on other apps.